# Issue with locating element by text (get element attribute)

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I have been struggling with this issue for longer time and finally decided to ask. I am quite new to robot framework, selenium and python and wanted to be sure that I checked everything.

So, my issue is with finding ID of a label. Below is label class which id I want to find

```
<label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="22_11_ahg_23" id="22_11_ahg_23-label">Full name</label>
```

And below is code I have written in robot framework to find this element

```
 ${full_name_id_-label}=  get element attribute     //*[contains(text(),'Full name')]   id
 Element Text Should Be      id=${full_name_id_-label}     Full name
```

2 second line is kind of debugger for me. I simply want to check whether id was found and stored in variable.
As a result I got 
*Element with locator 'id=' not found.*

I want to store id of this label as it is dynamically changing  (as well as id of input field next to it) and differences between id of input field and id of label is "-label" at the end.
I don't know how to locate input field in other way

```
<input id="22_11_ahg_23" class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="200" mask="" value="">
```

Does anyone can help me. Here are actually 2 questions:

1. What I am doing wrong that I cannot find element with locator -> actually why id is empty?
2. Is there any other way to locate such input field?

P.S. does somebody know how to get debugger working in robotframework in pycharm?

Answer (score 0):

After many tries I have found an issue.

It was "*" in xpath. It should be changed with "label" to work...